# Circuit Simulator for sampled Input

Tags: simulation

I would like to be able to capture a signal from my DSO and run it through a simulator to allow me to develop a simple analog preprocessor for a brushless motor speed sensor. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears to me as though Spice-style simulators won't help me here -- they will do DC, sine wave and impulse analysis, but won't simulate the response to an arbitrary waveform.

Is there a (free as in beer) simulator which would help me?

Answer (score 1):

I use micro-cap and have had real signals captures (in another programme) running in it. You can also define your own arbitrary waveforms and it will use these. It works with text files 
and there is a free student edition BUT I don't know if the free version will work.

Comment: Thanks I'll look at micro-cap -- interesting that it says it's spice based -- am I wrong about Spice in general not supporting arbitrary waveforms?

Comment: Try looking up user-defined-input - I'm sure that's what it's called in m-cap - it maybe the same name in others too